# Defining and organizing inner classes with Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently working on a complex Angular 2 component. Several of the private members of the component are custom objects I created. For instance :

```
private customDataGrid: CustomDataGrid;
```

The [angular style guide](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#application-structure-and-angular-modules) does not really mention any best practices regarding this scenario. So how to organize the code and the folder structure to maximize the re usability of my component ? Should I :

1. Declare my CustomDataGrid as an inner/nested class of my component ?
2. Declare my CustomDataGrid in a separate file located in the component folder ? If so what naming convention should I use ?
3. Move my CustomDataGrid to a module ?
4. Other ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to declare CustomDataGrid in a separate file located in the folder with the components that will be using it. If all components will be using it, consider putting it in a folder that contains other files used throughout the application and a module that declares and exports them accordingly. Name classes like this: class.ts.

See hero.ts in the [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html).

Answer (score 0):

Every file should have it's single purpose (also somewhere in the style guide or in a cookbook guide, can't find it right now sorry). Don't mix up multiple classes / interfaces or whatever in a single file. 
Use custom-data-grid.model.ts (see Style Guide "Interfaces") as a naming convention.
Consider implementing a class, so you could do

```
private customDataGrid: CustomDataGrid = new CustomDataGrid();
```

to apply default values etc. (only if it would be helpful in your case).